# Auto-generating a fully clocked agenda

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-agenda, org-clock, org-clock-table

Org agenda supports a powerful exporting function [`(org-agenda-write)`](https://orgmode.org/manual/Exporting-Agenda-Views.html), which exports your agenda view to `pdf`, `ps`, `html`.. format beautifully. In this post, I hope to make that process automatically.

More specifically, I'd like to have a cron job that handles everything. A function `(org-store-agenda-views)` that comes close is described in the same link above. However, after tinkering for two hours, I still can't find what I want.

Currently, I have to do it manually:

1. Enter org agenda.
2. Launch log view, so I can see exactly how the entries are clocked.
3. Launch clock report mode, so I get a nice time summary table.
4. Fire `(org-agenda-write)`.

As my attempt to do it automatically, I've tried

```
  (setq org-agenda-custom-commands
    '(("X" "EXPORT" ((agenda "" ((org-agenda-span 7)
                                 (org-agenda-log-mode-items '(closed clock state))
                                 (org-agenda-clockreport-mode t)
                                 (org-agenda-start-on-weekday 0))
                    )) nil (("~/agenda.html" "~/agenda.pdf"))))
```

as in the link. Notice that `org-agenda-log-mode-items` and `org-agenda-clockreport-mode` are the two closest variables I've found. But it did not affect the generated file..

#### Question

How to generate a full clocked agenda view automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Setting `org-agenda-log-mode-items` only affects what items get shown when log mode is on but doesn't turn on log mode.  To do that also set `org-agenda-start-with-log-mode` to `t`:

```
  (setq org-agenda-custom-commands
    '(("X" "EXPORT" ((agenda "" ((org-agenda-span 7)
                                 (org-agenda-start-with-log-mode t)
                                 (org-agenda-log-mode-items '(closed clock state))
                                 (org-agenda-clockreport-mode t)
                                 (org-agenda-start-on-weekday 0))
                    )) nil (("~/agenda.html" "~/agenda.pdf"))))
```

Comment: It does not change the exported file. However, by evaluating `(setq org-agenda-start-with-log-mode t)` first, the exported file changed! Thank you! But this does not work for `(setq org-agenda-start-with-clockreport-mode t)`. I'm still looking for a solution.